Why does there appear to be a straight line of red stars in this image of the Large Magellanic Cloud?
In this image of the Large Magellanic Cloud from the Spitzer space telescope, there's a straight line of red stars in the bottom right corner (much easier to see if you go to the link and open the full resolution, but that's a 58 MB image):

This seems to me unlikely to be represent the actual physical reality. The description states

This picture is a composite of infrared light captured by Spitzer.
Light with wavelengths of 3.6 (blue) and 8 (green) microns was
captured by the telescope's infrared array camera; 24-micron light
(red) was detected by the multiband imaging photometer.

Is this just an effect due to the underlying images which were composed together covering different areas?

Looks like a problem with creating a large mosaic of images.  The edge of the image in one wavelength does not match the edge of the image at another wavelength.

the two left corners are also missing the red channel.

Yeah, that looks like the red-channel sweep covered a slightly different section of the sky so it cuts out in some areas

Different but related (mosaic pattern issues) Why does one object (star?) in this JWST image have two sets of six+plus+two diffraction spikes but another, similar object nearby have only one? Peter Irwin's answer is very helpful!
